# Expand List Upward Over Other Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We're currently using a JS plugin called Nice Select which converts select inputs into expandable ul elements. I have the ul element at the bottom of an expandable hamburger menu. The number of li items at the bottom of the menu are causing the menu to overflow and have y-scroll. To prevent this, I would like the li items to expand upward on top of the other content in the menu. I've played around with relatively positioning the elements above the ul container but haven't had much success. I've posted here a quick example of the situation. Thanks for your help!

```js
$(function() {
  $('.list').toggle();
  $(".current").click(function() {
    $('.list').toggle();
  });
  $(".option").click(function() {
    $('.current').text($(this).text());
  });
})
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">

  </div>
  <div class="menu
  "><span class="current" style="">United States</span>
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="option">United Arab Emirates</li>
      <li class="option">United States</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've edited your example to provide a basic working version. I'm not entirely sure what you meant, so feel free to suggest some changes.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.list').toggle();
  $(".current").click(function() {
    $('.list').toggle();
  });
  $(".option").click(function() {
    $('.current').text($(this).text());
  });
})
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu {
  //
}

.menu ul {
  position: relative;
}

.menu ul li {
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">

  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <span class="current" style="">United States</span>
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="option">United Arab Emirates</li>
      <li class="option">United States</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.list').toggle();
  $(".current").click(function() {
    $('.list').toggle();
  });
  $(".option").click(function() {
    $('.current').text($(this).text());
  });
})
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu{
  position:relative;
}
.list{
position:absolute;
bottom:20px;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.list li{
background-color:white;
width:100%;
  display:block;
  border:1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">

  </div>
  <div class="menu
  "><span class="current" style="">United States</span>
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="option">United Arab Emirates</li>
      <li class="option">United States</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```